# Retrieve 'builtins' respectively by their types

Tags: python

I attempt to retrieve builtins by their types by the following steps

First ,Retrieve all the types in `builtins` using 'set'

```
total_builtins = dir(__builtins__)
total_types = {type(eval(i)) for i in total_builtins}
In [95]: total_types
Out[95]:
{NoneType,
 NotImplementedType,
 _sitebuiltins._Helper,
 _sitebuiltins._Printer,
 bool,
 builtin_function_or_method,
 ellipsis,
 function,
 method,
 str,
 type}
#Subtract type of 'type'
total_types = total_types.pop()
In [120]: len(total_types)
Out[120]: 10
```

Second group them using dict,

```
In [117]: {mytype:[i for i in total_bins if isinstance(eval(i), mytype)] 
          for mytype in total_types}
Out[117]:
{NoneType: ['None', '__loader__', '__package__', '__spec__'],
 NotImplementedType: ['NotImplemented'],
 _sitebuiltins._Helper: ['help'],
 _sitebuiltins._Printer: ['copyright', 'credits', 'license'],
 bool: ['False', 'True', '__IPYTHON__', '__debug__'],
 builtin_function_or_method: ['__build_class__',
  '__import__',
 ....],
 ellipsis: ['Ellipsis'],
 function: ['display'],
 method: ['get_ipython'],
 str: ['__doc__', '__name__']}
```

Which does produce the desired result but looks a bit too much for the task(especially the multiple nested comprehension).

How to solve such a problem in a smart way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could iterate over `__builtins__.__dict__`. Though, you'd still need to invert the dictionary after.

```
d = {k : type(v) for k, v in builtins.__dict__.items()}

d2 = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    d2.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

---

Similar solution with a `collections.defaultdict` -

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {k : type(v) for k, v in builtins.__dict__.items()}

d2 = defaultdict(list)    
for k, v in d.items():
    d2[v].append(k)
```

This happens to be a bit more efficient than the first solution.